# Vector space and linear span

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that goes:

> Let $V$ be a linear space and let $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be vectores in $V$ $(v_1 \neq v_2 \neq v_3)$. 
> Prove or Dismiss:
>
> If $span(v_1, v_2) = span(v_1, v_3)$ the vectores $v_2, v_3$ are linearly dependent.

Here's my take: 
$span(v_1, v_2) = span(v_1, v_3)$

So:
$\alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2 = \beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_3$

Which means:
$\alpha_2v_2 = \beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_3 - \alpha_1v_1  \Rightarrow v_2 = \frac{ v_1(\beta_1-\alpha_1)+\beta_2v_3}{\alpha_@}$

Which means that for $\alpha_1 \neq \beta_1$ and $v_1 \neq v_3$

We'll get that $v_2$ and $v_3$ are **linearly independent**.


Did I proved it right?
Thanks.

Comment: Even if you proved what you say you did, that is not what you were asked, which is: are $\;v_1,\, v_2\;$ lin. dep.?

Comment: Suppose $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $v_1=(1,0), v_2=(0,1), v_3=(1,1)$.

Comment: @DonAntonio My classmate tried to help me by giving an example which will contradict the claim. Let $v_1 = (1,0), v_2 = (0,1), v_1 = (1,2) in R^2$ It is obvious that these vectores are spans, and that $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent. But I dont understand why $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @lulu Exactly what my classmate tried to explain to me but forgive me, I really don't understand why why $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent in this example.

Comment: So, exhibit a dependence between them.

Comment: But, really, edit your post for clarity. What you wrote asks you to prove that $v_1,v_2$ are independent, but you keep talking about $v_2,v_3$.  Note that both are wrong (same counterexample) but you should get the question straight.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for pointing this out, I mistyped. I edited the question.